# ajax beginForm passing route value and button value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How would I get both param1 and param2 to my controller, I tried like this but only param1 gets passed.

```
  @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Controller", new { param1 = 0 }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "Target", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, OnFailure = "error" }))
               {
                    <input type="submit" name="param2" value="1" />
    //more buttons
               }


     public ActionResult Index(int param1, int param2)
            {
               //do something
            }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Controller", new { param1 = 0 }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId =    "Target", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, OnFailure = "error" }))
           {
                <input type="submit" name="param2" id="param2" value="1" />
//more buttons
           }


 public ActionResult Index(String param1, String param2)
        {
           //do something
        }
```

Is not it working ??

Comment: Ahh.. I wanted to avoid using hidden fields, anyway thanks this will do!

Comment: Yes it works, but I was hoping for solution without adding additional html to page.

Answer (score 3):

To set params like this:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "myController", new { param1 = 0, param2 = 1 }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId =    "Target", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, OnFailure = "error" }))
       {
            <input type="submit" />
            //more buttons
       }


    public ActionResult Index(String param1, String param2)
    {
       //do something
    }
```

you **MUST** map the relative route in the `RouteConfig.sc` before the `default' mapRoute :

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "routeName",
            url: "myController/Index/{param1}/{param2}",
            defaults: new { controller = "myController", action = "Index", param1 = UrlParameter.Optional, param2 = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Controller", new { param1 = 0 **,param2=1** }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "Target", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, OnFailure = "error" }))
{
    <input type="submit" name="param2" value="1" />
    //more buttons
}

public ActionResult Index(int param1, int param2)
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: param2 is dynamic value that depends on the button pressed.